# How to recognize objects or patterns in one image?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

suppose I have two images one contains circle and other contains square,I just want to give input as this images. program should recognize which one is circle and which one is square. how i can implement this using c# language?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection

Comment: Are the areas filled or just perimeters? Hand or program drawings?

Comment: @belisarius any circle or square/hand or program drawings.

Comment: @nik I suggest you to edit your question and add that info. It is relevant in order to get good answers.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few image recognition libraries out there. Try aforge: http://code.google.com/p/aforge/. Another one is EmguCV for .Net.

Answer (score 1):

using Emgu.CV:

exactly what you want:
http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Shape_(Triangle,_Rectangle,_Circle,_Line)_Detection_in_CSharp